# How can I make a working donation page using html and javascript?

Tags: html

On my recent question i got thumbs downed 8 times so hopefully this time i made this post proper enough. What im trying to do is make a donation page for my rsps(RuneScape Private Server). I need to add in some JavaScipt coding but im having trouble trying to add the right kind. What i want to happen is when someone selects an item from the item list i want the JavaScipt to recognize their selected item. After selecting an item they would then continue to enter their username on the sever and then click "submit" after clicking submit i would then like them to be redirected to the buy now page of their selected item. Per say if they chose donator i would like them to be directed towards the buy now page for donator. I am using plimus or also known as bluesnap.com

```
<div class="inner">
    <div class="wrapper contain separator-decorative separator-decorative-full">

            <h2 class="heading h1 teal">Zeus-Scape Donate</h2>
            <div class="text extra-classy">
                <h2><p>Please enter your username below and select the Item you wish to purchase</p></h2>
                <p>When donating you can select to purchase with, Paysafecard, Bank Transfer, Credit Card, Money Bookers and a few other options are available.</p>
                <p><strong>Once you have donated type ::donated in game to receive your items instantly with our automatic donation system!.</strong></p>
                <p>By Donating you agree to our <a href="./policy.php">Refund Policy</a>. If you disagree to our Refund Policy please leave this page.</p>


</div>
<center>
<html>

        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div name="select">
                Product:
                <select name="product">
<option value="3219084&templateId=937438">$80.00 - Drygore Weapon Set</option>
<option value="3219076&templateId=937438">$35.00 - Drygore Rapier</option>
<option value="3219078&templateId=937438">$35.00 - Drygore Longsword</option>
<option value="3219082&templateId=937438">$35.00 - Drygore Mace</option>
<option value="3194124&templateId=937438">$24.99 - Donator Boxes (x3)</option>
<option value="3195950&templateId=937438">$49.99 - Black Partyhat</option>
<option value="3194094&templateId=937438">$9.99 - Donator Status</option>
<option value="3194096&templateId=937438">$24.99 - Extreme Donator Status</option>
<option value="3194098&templateId=937438">$49.99 - VIP Donator Status</option>  
<option value="3194102&templateId=937438">$14.99 - Full Torva Armour Set</option>
<option value="3194104&templateId=937438">$14.99 - Full Pernix Armour Set</option>
<option value="3194106&templateId=937438">$14.99 - Full Virtus Armour Set</option>
<option value="3194108&templateId=937438">$39.99 - Full Primal Armour Set</option>
<option value="3194110&templateId=937438">$40.00 - Primal Weapon Set</option>
<option value="3194116&templateId=937438">$14.99 - Divine Spirit Shield</option>
<option value="3194120&templateId=937438">$14.99 - Arcane Spirit Shield</option>
<option value="3194118&templateId=937438">$14.99 - Elysian Spirit Shield</option>
<option value="3194122&templateId=937438">$39.99 - Spirit Shield Set</option>
<option value="3194112&templateId=937438">$9.99 - TokHaar-Kal & Fire Cape</option>
<option value="3202720&templateId=937438">$7.99 - 100 Squeal Of Fortune Spins</option>
<option value="3194114&templateId=937438">$14.99 - 200 Squeal Of Fortune Spins</option>
<option value="3197236&templateId=937438">$7.49 - Deathtouched Dart</option>
<option value="3199860&templateId=937438">$9.99 - Dragon Claws</option>
<option value="3199864&templateId=937438">$9.99 - Armadyl Godsword</option>
<option value="3206180&templateId=937438">$19.99 - Korasi</option>
<option value="3202718&templateId=937438">$4.99 - 200m Cash</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div name="username">
                Username:
                <input type="text" maxlength="12" name="username" value="Enter Username" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Username';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Username') this.value='';"/>
            </div>
                            <div name="button">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
<a href="http://www.plimus.com/ecommerce/buyers" target="_blank" title="Trusted and Secure Online Payment Processing via PLIMUS"><img src="https://www.plimus.com/images/icons_wizard/icons/cards/cards_type2_1-1.gif" border="0"></a>
        </center>

        <br>

        <br>
<center>

<p><strong> <a href="./donatepp.php">Click here to Donate using PayPal</a> </strong></p>

  </div> </div> </div></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail? You'll get better quality answers with more specific questions. Also, consider a writing style that is concise but detailed. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What i have been told is that my code only leads to a static url and it needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these tutorials:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm

Create a .js file containing your JavaScript code. Then, have the action attribute in your form tag take in your JavaScript file as its property.

```
<form action="file_name.js" method="POST">
```

Comment: these tutorials are close to what i need. the tutorial from w3schools is very close as it uses javascript to recognize the selected item. What it does that i dont need is make an alert. What i need it to do is recognize the selected item and lead the buyer to the buy now page of the selected item.

Comment: You can just omit the alert on w3schools if you don't need it. I just put them here as examples of how you can accomplish this. If you look at the tutorials point link, you can create a JavaScript method to redirect you to the page you want when a user submits the form, then pass in that JavaScript file as a property to the `form action`. JavaScript is a dynamic language by the way, in response to your comment above.